# How do I set up FTP on localhost?

Tags: ftp, localhost

On my old machine (back on Lucid!) I used XAMPP for local dev work. XAMPP installed everything for you, including setting up FTP to your localhost (/var/www) directory, since permissions don't allow you to write directly to it.

I have a new machine running Precise, and decided to do things the grown-up way. I installed everything using tasksel, and got apache, php, mysql, and phpmyadmin up and running. But it's kind of a pain to have to create and edit all my files via gksudo gedit on the command line, and sooner or later I'm going to have to upload images.

How can I set up FTP so that I can "upload" files to my localhost server?

**Edit to add**

Followed the first video, but when I got to the point where he was creating files (around 7:25 in), I get hung up. Here's what my terminal looks like when I try to get into the /srv directory (which I verified does exist in Nautilus):

[image]

What do I need to do to get past this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was just trying to do this exact same thing...

I looked it up on Youtube, he explains how to do it with a GUI. It is basically the same thing with a CLI, if that's what you are using, just all with text- obviously.

Here is part one editing the .conf file for vsftpd:

[Configuring FTP in Ubuntu - Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tanll-JM8y8)

And part two, where he finishes adding permissions and access control:

[Configuring FTP in Ubuntu - Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtHywU7EjVw)

Best of luck...

Comment: Thanks for the links. I followed the process to the letter, but got hung up around 7:26 in the first video - where he goes into the /srv folder to create files for testing. When I try that, it asks me for a password, which I obviously don't have since we haven't gotten to the point of creating accounts yet. (And yes, I did enable anonymous access in the .conf file.) Any idea why that's happening or how to get past it?

Comment: That one I'm not to sure about. I just know that the video worked for me. Sorry. :/

Comment: Any non-video answers?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293 here's a non video

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to get something similar to a trick of quickly starting HTTP server

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

which I use to download (not upload) files, i.e. I wanted something like this but for FTP server

- no security concerns about my network (e.g. localhost)
- no or minimal installation
- no configuration, like creating users, etc.
- no system-wide registration, I need this ftpd only once
- quickly start server and serve for the current path

I ended up with

```
sudo pip install pysendfile 
sudo pip install git+git://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib 
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib/master/demo/unix_ftpd.py 
sudo /usr/bin/python unix_ftpd.py
```

Your working folder should be the one to serve into. Tip: checkout on github there are more demos with other/no authorization handlers. Performance wise this python based server is not that bad if compared to vsftpd

Comment: note that the demo i downloaded does no jailroot to the working directory.. but gives access to the whole root fs

Answer (score 0):

You can use **vsftpd** to set up a local FTP server. Install it using

```
sudo apt install vsftpd
```

## Configuration

In your case, you'll have to update the config to allow users to log in to their home directories, by adding/uncommenting the following lines in `/etc/vsftpd.conf`:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

> **⚠ Warning:** This will allow any system user to sign in via FTP and use their username/and password to **read and modify** files. Be sure to disable it when not in use (see below).

Next, you will need to create a new user, setting the home directory to the your web root:

```
sudo adduser ftpuser
sudo usermod --home /var/www/html ftpuser
```

Restart the `vsftpd` server to use the updated settings:

```
sudo systemctl restart vsftpd
```

Now, you should be able to log in and modify files in `/var/www/html` by logging in using the username/password of the user you just created.

## Disabling the system

As a side-effect, the current setup also allows *any* system user to sign in via FTP using their username and password, which is a potential security risk. You can probably edit `/etc/vsftpd.conf` to fine-tune these permissions (I don't know it well enough to instruct you).

However, I would suggest disabling the vsftpd server when you are not using. This can be done with the following command:

```
sudo systemctl disable vsftpd
```

This will prevent vsftpd from starting automatically on boot. You can then manually start it using

```
sudo systemctl start vsftpd
```

and stop it again when you're done using it

```
sudo systemctl stop vsftpd
```

This will stop the vsftpd server and disable all FTP connections until you start it again.